# How can I turn on notifications on phone speakers when earphones are plugged in?

Tags: adb, notifications, miui, redmi, speaker

Phone: Redmi Note 8 Pro, MIUI Global 12.0.7.0 Stable (QGGMIXM), Android 10QP1A.190711.020

I can't seem to find a way to get notification sounds through my speakers if I have my earphones plugged in. Ringtones seem to be the only thing to work.

Apparently there's a [petition going around for Android 9](https://www.change.org/p/android-development-team-add-option-in-android-pie-to-enable-notification-sounds-from-device-when-headset-connected).

And there's mention of an option for audio routing on Android 10, which is the one I was able to update to, but I don't seem to find the option.

Is there a way to do this natively?
And if not, could I use ADB to solve this?
Assuming it's an Android property.